# SceneForm and Scenview in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I am following the below tutorial for rendering 3d model 
  https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/arcore-cupcakes-1-render-a-scene-without-ar-for-phones-without-arcore-27d61a43a130
  But when i run thee app app runs succesfully but empty screen is coming.

Comment: Can you please provide us some code that you have tried and the screenshot of the screen.

Comment: I used the below sample code   
  https://github.com/Hariofspades/ARExperiments/tree/master/render-scene-without-ar

Comment: And the screenshot? Please provide that also.

Comment: please check the screen shot https://imgur.com/a/PQvcwos    and the device i use is moto c plus 7.0 version

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Question on Stack Overflow should include the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Gourav thanks for the response do u get any solution im not sure what im missing or will the 3d renders in 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, The problem is with device ,It works with device or emulator having OS oreo 8.1 version

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give correct path of your 3d image folder. Then, only it will retrieve that image and display it on the screen.